# Flink's CoProcessFunction doesn't trigger onTimer

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I try to aggregate two streams like that

```
val joinedStream = finishResultStream.keyBy(_.searchId)
  .connect(startResultStream.keyBy(_.searchId))
  .process(new SomeCoProcessFunction)
```

and then working on them in `SomeCoProcessFunction` class like that

```
class SomeCoProcessFunction extends CoProcessFunction[SearchFinished, SearchCreated, SearchAggregated] {

   override def processElement1(finished: SearchFinished, ctx: CoProcessFunction[SearchFinished, SearchCreated, SearchAggregated]#Context, out: Collector[SearchAggregated]): Unit = { 

       // aggregating some "finished" data ...

   }

   override def processElement2(created: SearchCreated, ctx: CoProcessFunction[SearchFinished, SearchCreated, SearchAggregated]#Context, out: Collector[SearchAggregated]): Unit = {

       val timerService = ctx.timerService()
       timerService.registerEventTimeTimer(System.currentTimeMillis + 5000)

       // aggregating some "created" data ...
   }

   override def onTimer(timestamp: Long, ctx: CoProcessFunction[SearchFinished, SearchCreated, SearchAggregated]#OnTimerContext, out: Collector[SearchAggregated]): Unit = {

       val watermark: Long = ctx.timerService().currentWatermark()
       println(s"watermark!!!! $watermark")

       // clean up the state

   }
```

What I want is to clean up the state after a certain time( 5000 Milliseconds), and that is what `onTimer` have to be used for. But since it never get fired, I kinda ask my self what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for any hint.

**UPDATE:**

Solution was to set timeService like that (tnx to both fabian-hueske and Beckham):

`timerService.registerProcessingTimeTimer(timerService.currentProcessingTime() + 5000)`

I still didn't really figure out what `timerService.registerEventTimeTimer` does, watermark  `ctx.timerService().currentWatermark()` shows always `-9223372036854775808` now matter how long before EventTimer was registered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are registering an event-time timer (`timerService.registerEventTimeTimer`) with a processing-time timestamp (`System.currentTimeMillis + 5000`).

`System.currentTimeMillis` returns the current machine time but event-time is not based on the machine time but on the time computed from watermarks.

Either you should register a processing-timer or register an event-time timer with an event-time timestamp. You can get the timestamp of the current watermark or the timestamp of the current record from the `Context` object that is passed as a parameter to `processElement1()` and `processElement2()`.

Answer (score 3):

I see that you are using `System.currentTimeMillis` which might be different from the `TimeCharacteristic` (event time, processing time, ingestion time) that your Flink job uses.

Try getting the timestamp of the event `ctx.timestamp()` then add the 5000ms on top of it.